# Plugin support in Enterprise Architect

Tags: plugins, enterprise-architect

I'm looking for API to extract data from models, however I can't seem to find  if Enterprise Architect supports user made plugins similar to MagicDraw UML (via so called open API) or Visual paradigm do? I just need to be able to gather data from model, nothing fancy.

Example:

- [Magic Draw plugin support](http://mdwhatever.free.fr/index.php/2010/03/how-to-develop-your-magicdraw-plugin/)
- [Visual paradigm plugins](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/tutorials/plugin.jsp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There sure is, there is a great community who have produced 3rd party add-ins for enterprise architect. The following link is to the Sparx Systems website in the [Enterprise Architect Web Documentation](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/automation/automation_interface.html) which you will find a link to the EA Object model.

They also have base add-ins that you can download and extend available from their [resources section](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/developers/autint.html).

I hope this helps!

TomO